# Request a simple alembic working example for Auto Generating Migrations

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, data-migration, alembic

I installed alembic 0.3.4, sqlalchemy, SQLite version 3.7.4, and upgraded SQLAlchemy 0.6.4 to SQLAlchemy 0.7 or greater from my ubuntu.
I followed [the instructions linked here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160616142640/https://alembic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html):

Now I am testing: Auto Generating Migrations
I have created a package: schemas, and a package marker under schemas: *init*.py
with one line defined:

```
__all__ = ["teacher"]
```

I also created a module file: dbmodel.py in schemas directory with below content

```
Base = declarative_base()
class teacher(Base):
      __tablename__ = 'teacher' 
      id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
      name = Column(String)
      department = Column(String)
```

By the way, I have a sqlite db created, and it is running fine for doing some test before Auto Generating Migrations. I configured the env.py file. There are two lines added:

```
from schemas.dbmodel import Base
target_metadata = Base.metadata
```

Then I run:

```
alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Added teacher table"
```

but still get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/alembic", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('alembic==0.3.4', 'console_scripts', 'alembic')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/alembic-0.3.4-py2.7.egg/alembic/config.py", line 229, in main
    **dict((k, getattr(options, k)) for k in kwarg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/alembic-0.3.4-py2.7.egg/alembic/command.py", line 93, in revision
    script.run_env()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/alembic-0.3.4-py2.7.egg/alembic/script.py", line 188, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, 'env.py')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/alembic-0.3.4-py2.7.egg/alembic/util.py", line 185, in load_python_file
    module = imp.load_source(module_id, path, open(path, 'rb'))
  File "alembic/env.py", line 20, in <module>
    from schemas.dbmodel import Base
ImportError: No module named schemas.dbmodel
```

I don't know why it is so difficult for me to test a simple example using alembic. I just want to import my application data model into the physical database model. Is that so complicated? Thanks. Please somebody who knows alembic gives us a simple exaple step by step. I guess more people will get benefit from that.

Comment: So where in your code is the url to the sqlite database? I got this to work from an existing pyramid application that was using sqlalchemy-migrations. In order to get this to work I had to bootstrap the url/db connection as pyramid does and then to load up my model Base from there. https://github.com/mitechie/Bookie/blob/develop/dbversions/env.py#L12

Comment: In file: alembic.ini, I configured it and added one line:   sqlalchemy.url =sqlite:///test    This worked for migrating schema change to my test DB.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I also found that Alembic couldn't find my model modules. As a workaround, I found that, by adding the following to my `env.py` before importing my models, I could force it to work:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
```

This is probably not the best solution, but it got Alembic to autogenerate my migrations.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, although my code still has some problem, at least the data module path works fine now. You save me lots of time :)

Comment: I recently found out that we need to configure the PYTHONMATH variable by adding the current module path. It works.

Comment: I was facing a similar problem and now it works.. Here is the question and the answer that solved my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038036/integrating-alembic-with-sqlalchemy

Comment: Tried that, I get ImportError on configuration package. here is what I have added `import os
    import sys

    sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
    from configuration import app, db`