# Alembic: alembic revision says Import Error

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic

I am trying to integrate my `Flask` project with `Alembic`
My application structure looks like

```
project/
       configuration/
                    __init__.py
                    dev.py
                    test.py
       core/
           # all source code
       db/
         migrations/
                    __init__.py
                    alembic.ini
                    env.py
                    versions/
```

When I try to run the following from my `db` directory, I see

```
 File "migration/env.py", line 55, in run_migrations_online
    from configuration import app, db
ImportError: No module named configuration
```

I tried the solution mentioned in [Request a simple alembic working example for Auto Generating Migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276017/request-a-simple-alembic-working-example-for-auto-generating-migrations), but it does not work for me

My method in `env.py` `run_migrations_online()` with change is

```
def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    import os
    import sys

    sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
    from configuration import app, db

    alembic_config = config.get_section(config.config_ini_section)
    alembic_config['sqlalchemy.url'] = app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']
    target_metadata = db.metadata

    engine = engine_from_config(
        alembic_config,
        prefix='sqlalchemy.',
        poolclass=pool.NullPool)

    connection = engine.connect()
    context.configure(
        connection=connection,
        target_metadata=target_metadata
    )

    try:
        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()
    finally:
        connection.close()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I did `export PYTHONPATH=<path_to_project>` and ran the command again and it ran successfully

Comment: For a better, more permanent solution, I second what @Palasaty suggested. Just update your `env.py` file to use the correct directory.

Comment: My preferred solution echos @zzzeek's suggestion to use revision_environment=True to get revisions to use the `env.py`: https://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/tutorial.html?highlight=revision_environment#editing-the-ini-file

Comment: PYTHONPATH=. willl include the current directory and it will do the trick as well.

Comment: If your setup is docker-compose you can set this variable like: `docker-compose run --rm -e PYTHONPATH=. <container_name> alembic <alembic_command>` for 1 time commands.

Answer (score 20):

You say you run something like `alembic migrate --autogenerate -m 'migration description'` from the directory `project/db` and get `ImportError`, right?

If so, the problem is obvious.

See: you try to import `configuration` module and it results in errors. Then you put `sys.path.append(os.getcwd())` - in other words, you add *current* directory to the system path. But what is the current directory? It's `project/db`, and it doesn't have `configuration` module under it, so you continue getting `ImportError`.

Solution is to add to system path parent directory - `project`, which contains `configuration` module. Like so:

```
parent_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), ".."))
sys.path.append(parent_dir)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this answer  didn't work for me. I'm using @daydreamer's solution, I run my commands `PYTHONPATH=. alembic <command_name>`.

Comment: this answered worked for me,

Answer (score 2):

We've run into the same problem, it boils down to env.py not being called by revision **unless** the `--autogenerate` flag is set. You can test this by putting a print statement at the top of your env.py file.

We're working around it by calling with `--autogenerate` then removing the generated code.

Comment: note you don't need --autogenerate, please use revision_environment=True:   http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/tutorial.html?highlight=revision_environment#editing-the-ini-file

Comment: Have you found another way of envoking the `env.py` file without using `--autogenerate` ?

Comment: @zzzeek I tried using `revision_environment=true` but I'm seeing same issue.

Comment: The t in your `true` needs to be a capital T. It is Python.

Comment: @dbinott it isn't python code, zzzeek is refering to the alembic.ini file from the shared link. BTW, I still have to use PYTHONPATH=. , revision_environment=true doesn't fix it for me (also tried True capital T)

Answer (score 1):

For those who don't want to set `PYTHONPATH` manually before running alembic.
You may run alembic as a module, for instance:

```
python -m alembic.config upgrade head
```