# Do "alembic current" and "alembic history" search different paths?

Tags: python, alembic

I'm using Alembic with SQLAlchemy to do a *schema migration* and a [*data migration*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24623979/7232335).

Since I have stored migration-specific dependencies in their own module within my project's main application `myapp` (as per [Michael Bayer's recommendation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy-alembic/zo25kI4WKvw)), I have run into `ModuleNotFoundError`s when running `alembic current` and `alembic history`.

As [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15734665/7232335), I have added the repository directory `project` to my system path by adding the following to `env.py`.

```
# Add project to path.
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
```

This fixes the `ModuleNotFoundError` for `alembic current`, **but not** `alembic history`.

Why do these two commands give different results?

---

Repository structure:

```
project
│   alembic.ini
│   db.sqlite
│
├───alembic
│   │   env.py
│   │   README
│   │   script.py.mako
│   │
│   └───versions
│           2b939015022a_create_athlete_table.py
│           3649f2977ae1_migrate_athletes_to_star_athletes.py
│
└───myapp
    └───migrations
            star_athlete.py
```

Migration script:

```
"""migrate athletes to star_athletes

Revision ID: 3649f2977ae1
Revises: 2b939015022a
Create Date: 2019-06-12 09:46:16.173048

"""
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa

# This line causes ModuleNotFoundError
from myapp.migrations.star_athlete import StarAthlete


# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = '3649f2977ae1'
down_revision = '2b939015022a'
branch_labels = None
depends_on = None


def upgrade():
    print('upgrading...')


def downgrade():
    print('downgrading...')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because the import path is modified by Alembic's `env.py` (even prior to your modifications), but by default `env.py` is not executed by `alembic history`. You can fix this by setting `revision_environment = true` in `alembic.ini`.