# Alembic not able to import flask application ORM models

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic

### **Use case:**

I'm attempting to create a migration script that will create a table (which will make a many to many relationship) and then populate that table with foreign keys from the database.

To do this I'm attempting to load my flask applications ORM models so that I may use them in my migration script.

### **directory structure**

```
/home/alord/git/my_project/  #  project directory
/home/alord/git/my_project/alembic_testing  #  migration directory
/home/alord/git/my_project/my_project #requirement of flask modules
/home/alord/git/my_project/runserver.py  #  script that starts development server
/home/alord/git/my_project/alembic.ini  #  alembic configuration
/home/alord/git/my_project/development_config.py  #  development server configuration
```

if I run alembic upgrade +1

```
import os
print os.getcwd()
print os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

in

```
/home/alord/git/my_project/alembic_testing/env.py
```

I get

```
/home/alord/git/my_project
/home/alord/git/my_project/alembic_testing
```

### **What I'm doing**

I'm placing

```
import os.path
sys.path.append(
    os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir)))
import my_project
```

In my upgrade script and then running the command

```
alembic upgrade +1
```

and I'm recieving a stack trace with the error

```
ImportError: No module named my_project
```

Without this attempted import the table upgrade and downgrade functions run without error.

### **What I expect**

I would like to be able to import the package, and more importantly *my_project.models* so that I can use the ORM to populate my new table.

**Note:**
I can't use relative package inclusion because I'm running alembic rather than calling python. As such, the python -m argument isn't useful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Short answer:**

trying to inport from a revision file in alembic puts you two directories down instead of one.

### **Long answer:**

So I ended up printing off my *sys.path* to see what directories were actually included. When I noticed that the path that was included was

```
/home/alord/git/my_project/alembic_testing
```

instead of

```
/home/alord/git/my_project/alembic_testing
```

I made my path.append go up one more directory using,

```
import sys
import os.path

#hacky solution to get to the root application directory.
sys.path.append(
        os.path.abspath(
            os.path.join(
                os.path.join(
                    os.path.dirname(__file__),
                    os.path.pardir),
                os.path.pardir)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix your `script_location` in `alembic.ini` to point to the right place, then just run `alembic` from the root of your repository (`/home/alord/git/`), and you shouldn't need any `sys.path` hijinks to be able to import your app.

Comment: my script location points to the alembic_testing folder and I'm still  running into this error.

Comment: I gave you the wrong directory structure in my example paths. This answer does not work for my problem.

Comment: i don't see why it wouldn't, but i don't have any further insight without more information

Comment: [For the same reason that Alembic has trouble finding models meta data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276017/request-a-simple-alembic-working-example-for-auto-generating-migrations/11280521#11280521)